# LINQ ToDictionary how to get item index?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I've a Dictionary, which I want to convert to another Dictionary, using the rule implied by below sample:

Inputs:

```
Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>(3)
{
   { "A", "First" },
   { "Z", "Third" },
   { "J", "Second" }
};
```

Output:

```
Dictionary<int, string> output = new Dictionary<string, string>(3)
{
   { 0, "First" },
   { 1, "Second" },
   { 2, "Third" }
};
```

Can I do it using lambda syntax & no intermediary objects?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, John! Just had the same question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The order of enumeration of a dictionary is indeterminate (i.e. items don't have an index), so I'm not sure that this is possible. How would the integer values be derived?

EDIT:

I get it now:

```
inputs
    .OrderBy(input => input.Key)
    .Select((input, index) => new {index, input.Value})
    .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.Value)
```

Comment: Index is a rank in a dictionary sorted by key.

Answer (score 2):

If you can define what the ordering should be, then I would do it like this (I chose to order by key):

```
Dictionary<string, string> inputs = new Dictionary<string, string>(3)
{
   { "A", "First" },
   { "Z", "Third" },
   { "J", "Second" }
};

var outputs = inputs.OrderBy(i=>i.Key).Select(i=>i.Value).ToArray();

// output
// String [] (3 items):
First 
Second
Third
```

This gives you an array with the indices that you asked for (e.g. `output[0]`).

If you really want dictionary entries back, you can get an ienumerable of them like this (you can't just return a dictionary because they're unordered):

```
var outputs = inputs.OrderBy(i=>i.Key).Select(
  (entry, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(index, entry.Value));
```

Throw a `.ToArray()` on there if you need to.

If you really want a dictionary back, try this:

```
var outputs = inputs.OrderBy(i=>i.Key)
                    .Select((entry, i) => new { entry.Value, i })
                    .ToDictionary(pair=>pair.i, pair=>pair.Value).Dump();
```

Just keep in mind that dictionaries are not inherently ordered so if you enumerate over it, you should add a `.OrderBy` again.

Comment: Any chance to get the result as Dictionary<int, string> as opposed to var?